# Debugging in Visual Studio : Breakpoint moves and inserts a new line

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

I am a beginner with Visual Studio and I am encounting a problem when I am in the Debug Mode.

I did not have this problem at first, and now it happens more and more.
This is what happens :

I am debugging my project and I hit a breakpoint. So I press F5 to continue debugging, and then a new line is inserted just before the line with the breakpoint, and the program continues debugging. Problem is it modifies my code...
The problem does not occur when I press F10 or F11 (but it still happens later when I press F5). And it does not occur everywhere in the code, just with some lines, especially the new ones.

I have tried many things like : 
restart VS, clean solution, delete .pdb, make sure I have the good type of linefeed.

Please help me !
:)

Comment: If timocov's answer didn't help, did you try replacing your keyboard? If this is a laptop, does this happen more based on how you're holding it? (I have a laptop that randomly generates `;`s when pressing on the bottom)

Comment: I tried what timocov said but it did not work.
I think the problem does not come from the keyboard because when I click on the button/Icon "Continue" in Visual, the same problem occurs

Answer (score 0):

Check your Keyboard settings at Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard.
Try press F5 in `Press shortcut keys` input and see at "Shortcut currently used by".
In my case there is only "Debug.Start (F5 (Global))".

If you have other commands, try to remove it.

Comment: May be you have some macroses which do it? (Tools->Macros->Macros IDE)

Comment: I don't have macro tool  (I can not find it)